# How to find the position of an element relative to it's parent in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So I have a component that I'm building in vue.js, it is a list of items that has a absolute positioned pointer pointing to the active/hovered item.
So I have to get the position of the hovered/active list item so I can send those Y coordinates to the pointer.

I want the pointer to move on a Y axis up and down through the list ending at the centre of the active items position.

What I currently have works if the component is at the 0, 0 position in the window, if I add for example a paragraph of text above that component, the measurements are off by the height of that paragraph.

Now obviously the component won't be at the 0,0 point of the page, and the page will probably also be overflowing (scrollable).

So on mouseenter, mouseleave and click events I'm setting the $event.target to be the active item.

This is the function I'm using to get the centre of the list-item.

```
 getCenterOfRow(elem) {
        return (
            (elem.getBoundingClientRect().top +
                elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom) /
            2
        )
    }
```

I also tried this way of doing it.

```
 getCenterOfRow(elem) {
        let topOffset = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
        while (elem != document.documentElement) {
            elem = elem.parentElement
            topOffset += elem.scrollTop
        }
        return topOffset
    }
```

They both give me the same result.

What can I do better so I can have that pointer only measure from the top of the parent?

Comment: Quote MDN on getBoundingClientRect: _"Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of the viewport."_ - so get the viewport offset for your parent element as well, and then calculate the offset from the parent via those two.

Comment: So i just got it..the correct solution for me was to use el.offsetTop - which is the number of pixels between the top edge of the element and the top edge of its offset parent.
I add to that the height of the element and devided by 2 to get the centre of the element.
``
return elem.offsetTop + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2

``